# SharedPreferences in android service

Tags: android, service, sharedpreferences

I made timer, and it works on service instead of normal activity.

And now I want to store millisUntilFinished in SharedPreferences(RT_MATH) every second to make pause function(I will reload it when the timer is resumed), but when I run this activity(timer.start()), it have error. What I have to do??

```
package com.p.k;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Math_Service extends Service {

SharedPreferences prefs;

public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

   prefs = getSharedPreferences("RT_MATH", MODE_PRIVATE);

}

long rt_math = Long.parseLong(((prefs.getString("rt_math", "6000000"))));
final CounterClass timer = new CounterClass(rt_math, 1000);

public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();


    timer.cancel();
}

public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

    timer.start();
    return START_STICKY;

}

public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

public class CounterClass extends CountDownTimer {
    public CounterClass(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
        super((millisInFuture), countDownInterval);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        String hms = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millisUntilFinished),
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millisUntilFinished)),
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished)));

        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("RT_MATH", MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putString("rt_math", String.valueOf(millisUntilFinished));
        editor.commit();

    }
}

}
```

And it's my error.

```
10-30 02:04:59.480 13178-13178/com.p.k E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate service com.p.k.Math_Service: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-30 02:04:59.480 13178-13178/com.p.k E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2249)
10-30 02:04:59.480 13178-13178/com.p.k E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:127)
10-30 02:04:59.480 13178-13178/com.p.k E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1213)
10-30 02:04:59.480 13178-13178/com.p.k E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-30 02:04:59.480 13178-13178/com.p.k E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-30 02:04:59.480 13178-13178/com.p.k E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4512)
10-30 02:04:59.480 13178-13178/com.p.k E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-30 02:04:59.480 13178-13178/com.p.k E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-30 02:04:59.480 13178-13178/com.p.k E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:978)
10-30 02:04:59.480 13178-13178/com.p.k E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:745)
10-30 02:04:59.480 13178-13178/com.p.k E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-30 02:04:59.480 13178-13178/com.p.k E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-30 02:04:59.480 13178-13178/com.p.k E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.p.k.Math_Service.<init>(Math_Service.java:23)
10-30 02:04:59.480 13178-13178/com.p.k E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
10-30 02:04:59.480 13178-13178/com.p.k E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
10-30 02:04:59.480 13178-13178/com.p.k E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2246)
10-30 02:04:59.480 13178-13178/com.p.k E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:127) 
10-30 02:04:59.480 13178-13178/com.p.k E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1213) 
10-30 02:04:59.480 13178-13178/com.p.k E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
10-30 02:04:59.480 13178-13178/com.p.k E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
10-30 02:04:59.480 13178-13178/com.p.k E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4512) 
10-30 02:04:59.480 13178-13178/com.p.k E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
10-30 02:04:59.480 13178-13178/com.p.k E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
10-30 02:04:59.480 13178-13178/com.p.k E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:978) 
10-30 02:04:59.480 13178-13178/com.p.k E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:745) 
10-30 02:04:59.480 13178-13178/com.p.k E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is wrong as `prefs` will be `null` here.

```
long rt_math = Long.parseLong(((prefs.getString("rt_math", "6000000"))));
```

You should initilize this variable in `onCreate` Method instead.

```
long rt_math;
CounterClass timer;

public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    prefs = getSharedPreferences("RT_MATH", MODE_PRIVATE);
    rt_math = Long.parseLong(((prefs.getString("rt_math", "6000000"))));
    timer = new CounterClass(rt_math, 1000);
}
```

Comment: @KMJ I'm glad that it helped you. :-)